# How to persist mysql connection (mysql2 gem) with Ruby (no RoR)

Tags: ruby, rack, mysql2

I have a very simple web service using Rack, without Rails that I will contact MySQL on every valid connection. I want to persist the connection (for example in the constructor), so that on every request I reuse it. Lets say something like this:

```
  class Service

    def initialize(dbhost, dbport, dbname, dbuser, dbpass)
      @client = Mysql2::Client.new(
          :host => dbhost, 
          :port => dbport, 
          :database => dbname,
          :username => dbuser, 
          :password => dbpass)
    end

    def call(env)
       # some logic that will call:
       results = _query(sql)
    end

    def _query(sql)
      results = @client.query(sql)
    end

  end

  Rack::Handler::Mongrel.run Service.new(DB_HOST, DB_PORT, DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS), :Port => 8123
```

With the code above, the service will obtain a MySQL connection and on every request it will do a query. But how do I make sure that if the connection drops, the `_query` method will reconnect?

Comment: are you sure the connection is establish on every request Can you check If yes it would be weird because normally that doesnot happen

Comment: It is not! As I've said, I want to establish and persist it only once and reuse it in `_query` method. I want to be able to handle situation where it drops.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong `It is not` what not over here does it make connection everytime or doesnot make connection everytime as I said before Rack does behave the way you mention above i.e any `middleware new` is only called once during at the time when middelware stack is build that it so w.r.s.t the code you connection persit

Comment: I do not understand if you are arguing about something. The mysql connection is created in the construct. Then the service can work with months. Meanwhile only the "call" method will be called. So if the MySQL connection drops, will the call method still be able to execute queries (will it recover the connection)?

Comment: I think you need to update the question then I got confuse at first reading it btw does this help `https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2#connection-options`

Comment: @Vaseliq btw the important thing over here is `reconnect` set it to true

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, `:reconnect => true` seems to ensure that the connection is persisted.

```
  @client = Mysql2::Client.new(
      :host => dbhost, 
      :port => dbport, 
      :database => dbname,
      :username => dbuser, 
      :password => dbpass,
      :reconnect => true
      )
```